# page progress bar in Yeoman/angular signup page

Tags: angularjs, progress-bar, yeoman, mean-stack

Hi I'm just learning angular, and I was wondering if someone could let me know what I'm doing wrong with setting up this simple load bar in the Yeoman signup page

In the signup.controller.js, I have the following code:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('lolBetApp')
  .controller('SignupCtrl', function ($scope, $http, Auth, $location) {
$scope.user = {};
$scope.errors = {};

$scope.register = function(form) {
  $scope.submitted = true;

  if(form.$valid) {
    Auth.createUser({
      summonerName: $scope.user.summonerName,
      email: $scope.user.email,
      password: $scope.user.password
    })
    .then( function() {
      // Account created, redirect to home
      $location.path('/');
    })
    .catch( function(err) {
      err = err.data;
      $scope.errors = {};

      // Update validity of form fields that match the mongoose errors
      angular.forEach(err.errors, function(error, field) {
        form[field].$setValidity('mongoose', false);
        $scope.errors[field] = error.message;
      });
    });
  }
};

$scope.$emit('LOAD')
$http.jsonp('http://filltext.com/?rows=10&delay=5&fname={firstName}&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
.success(function(data){
  $scope.people=data;
  $scope.$emit('UNLOAD')
});

 }).
 controller('loaderController',['$scope',function($scope){
  $scope.$on('LOAD',function(){$scope.loading=true});
  $scope.$on('UNLOAD',function(){$scope.loading=false });
}]);
```

And in my signup.html, I have the following code:

```
<div ng-controller="loaderController"> 
<div class="alert alert-info" ng-show="loading">Summoning...</div>
<div ng-controller="myController">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in people">
      {{person.fname}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I was able to get this to work easily without using Yeoman, using the code in this link http://plnkr.co/edit/30qbDj0xuBESp6LT8etM?p=info

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! I just got it to work. The problem is that I had the wrong name for the controller in the signup.html page

```
 <div ng-controller="SignupCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in people">
      {{person.fname}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```